# Cannot grant MySQL user access to information_schema database

Tags: mysql, laravel, ubuntu

I am creating a Laravel App and testing it in production mode on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 19.10.03.  Fresh LAMP installation (PHP 7.3, MySQL 8.0.19-0).

I can create a new database, and a new user that has full access to the database, but Laravel requires that the user have the SELECT option from the 'information_schema' database as well.  Here is the process I am using:

```
$ sudo mysql

mysql> CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `my-laravel-database`;
mysql> CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'laravelUser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'myPass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `my-laravel-database`.* TO 'laravelUser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> GRANT SELECT ON `information_schema`.* TO 'laravelUser'@'localhost';
```

The last command always returns

```
ERROR 1044 (4200): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'
```

I have tried running the `mysql_secure_installation` command to set the root password, this did not help.  I can run the app as the root user, but I do not want to do this in production.

I have also tried a fresh installation of Ubuntu with just the LAMP services installed.

Comment: Can you check your `.env` file? From the error, it seems `DB_USERNAME` in your `.env` file is set to `root`. If you have changed it and still getting this error try to clear cache using the `php artisan cache:clear` command in console/terminal or `Artisan::call('cache:clear');` in your route file.

Comment: I'm doing this manually in the ubuntu command prompt, not through laravel.

Answer (score 5):

I wasted DAYS on something tangential to this problem. The answer was [in the MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema-introduction.html#information-schema-privileges):

> For most INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables, **each MySQL user has the right to access them**, but can see only the rows in the tables that correspond to objects for which the user has the proper access privileges.

So you can't grant permission to `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` directly, you have to grant permission to the tables on your own schemas, and as you do, those tables will start showing up in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` queries.

Unfortunate, because I'd love have a user who's able to see `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, but not the content of the actual tables, and there doesn't seem to be a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. `USE mysql;`
2. `ANALYZE TABLE db;`
    
   In case table is broken run the following:
3. `REPAIR TABLE db;`

Then restart MySQL server.

Comment: The Status shows ok when I do the ```analyze table db```.  If I try to do a repair, I get an error ```The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair```